# MPI_Isend of root process never arrives

Tags: c++, mpi, mpich

I'm working on asynchronous communication and plan to implement the following routine: Each process owns a vector of processes it has to communicate with, in ascending order. It posts a nonblocking receive to all smaller ranks and a nonblocking send to all larger ranks. For all processes, except process 0, this works. What is my problem?

I have already checked via command line outputs that every process posts the number of receives and sends it should, in the right order and with the correct information. Also, using unistd.h, I've called sleep(5) to check if the communication is successful after some time. I've checked (using Probe and blocking MPI_Recv) that the message is actually on its way - it just never seems to arrive if I use the MPI_Irecv.

To understand the code: rank is the rank of the current process, commRanks is the vector of processes to communicate with. recvRanks is where the message content will be stored. reqsArray is an array of requests, it's the same size as commRanks. rankIndex and index iterate from commRanks.begin() to commRanks.end() and from 0 to commRanks.size(), respectively.

```cpp
std::vector<int> recvRanks;

for ( rankIndex = commRanks.begin(); *rankIndex < rank && rankIndex != domain->commRanks.end() ; rankIndex++ ) {
  //initialize recv buffer to -1 to see if communication works:
  recvRanks.push_back(-1);
  MPI_Irecv(&recvRanks.at(index),1,DT_RANK_MPI,*rankIndex,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqsArray[index]);
  index++;
}

if (*rankIndex == rank) {
  *rankIndex++;
  index++;
}

for ( ; rankIndex != domain->commRanks.end() ; rankIndex++ ) {
  MPI_Isend(&rank,1,DT_RANK_MPI,*rankIndex,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&reqsArray[index]);
  index++;
}

sleep(5);

//check if communication was successful:
printf("process 0: [ ");
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < recvRanks.size(); i++){
 printf("%d ", recvRanks.at(i));
}
printf("]\n");
```

I would expect the output to be:

process 0: [ ]

process 1: [ 0 ]

process 2: [ 0 1 ]

process 3: [ 0 1 2 ]

...

Actual result:

process 0: [ ]

process 1: [ -1 ]

process 2: [ -1 1 ]

process 3: [ -1 1 2 ]

...

So the Isend of process 0 never completes - what have I done wrong? If you need any more info to understand the question, please let me know! I've been stuck at this point for one week now.

Answer (score 0):

After posting some of your `MPI_Irecv`s, `recvRanks` reallocates on `push_back`, invalidating the pointers to its elements already provided as buffers.  Use `reserve` first to prevent reallocation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It did not solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @ValentinaSchüller: Well, then post an MCVE (including `reserve` or just `std::vector<int> recvRanks(commRanks.size(),-1);`); it’s hard to do more than point out the obvious with only a code fragment.